# Dart: checking if an object implements interface

Tags: flutter, inheritance, dart, interface

I have the following classes and interfaces:

```dart
class Place extends Entity
    with ChangeNotifier, FieldGetters
    implements Scannable, Likable {
// ...some stuff
}
```

```dart
abstract class Likable {
// ... some stuff
}
```

`Entity` is just a base class for other classes.

So, the problem is that I want to check whether the object that implements the `Likable` interface is of class `Place` or not. To do so, I use the following code:

```dart
logger.i('likable is ${like.likable.runtimeType}');
logger.i('likable is Place: ${like.likable is Place}');
```

The first line works as expected and shows the following output:

```
I/flutter ( 1635): [38;5;12m┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[0m
I/flutter ( 1635): [38;5;12m├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄[0m
I/flutter ( 1635): [38;5;12m│  likable is Place[0m
I/flutter ( 1635): [38;5;12m└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[0m
```

However, the second line of code acts weird and shows the following:

```
I/flutter ( 1635): [38;5;12m┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[0m
I/flutter ( 1635): [38;5;12m├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄[0m
I/flutter ( 1635): [38;5;12m│  likable is Place: false[0m
I/flutter ( 1635): [38;5;12m└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[0m
```

The official documentation suggests that the interface inheritance can be checked via `is` keyword. I am confused. How can I check the interface inheritance in this case?

**Dart**: `v2.8.1`

**Flutter**: `v1.17.0`

Comment: The `is` keyword should work. [I cannot reproduce your problem.](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e769f5a695b274bf91429ffacd0d175b)  Please post a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Answer (score 3):

In Dart a class can only inherit from one superclass (for `Place` it is `Entity`) and `implement` from multiple (i.e. grab functions from those classes).

As far as I could understand from your description, you are doing something like this (you can run it [here](https://dartpad.dev/)).

```
class Person extends LivingCreature implements Mammal{
  final _name;
  void _toDrinkMilk(){
    print("I drink milk as a person!");
  }
  Person(this._name);
}

class Mammal {
  void _toDrinkMilk(){
    print("I drink milk!");
  }
}

class LivingCreature {

  void _toLive(){
    print("I live!");
  }
}

void main() {
  final bob = Person('Bob');
  final mammal = Mammal();
  print(mammal is LivingCreature);
  print(bob.runtimeType);
  bob._toDrinkMilk();
  bob._toLive();
  print('Bob is mammal: ${bob is Mammal}');
  print('Mammal is Person: ${mammal is Person}');
}
```

And this code yields following output:

```
true
Person
I drink milk as a person!
I live!
Bob is mammal: true
Mammal is Person: false
```

So, now let us talk about what just happens in your case, your `like.likable` should be a `Likable` abstract class (I assume). `Place` in the meantime implements `Likable`, so it should implement all methods of `Likable`.

Now, you are trying to ask Dart is the type of your `Likable` (which does not extend or implement anything) is `Place`, which is `false` as given in the log.

If it has been `class Likable extends Place {...` then in the log you would have `like.likable is Place` be equal to `true`

For more on extends, implements, with you can refer to the [Dart docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators)

P.S. I did not make Mammal abstract to instantiate it quickly in print()

Hope it helps!